# Ionic 3 ViewChild undefined on subscribe

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, undefined, viewchild

I have a component and a ViewChild to get its instance, but when I'm trying to load, it returns undefined. Here is my code

```
@ViewChild('mapComponent')      mapComponent    :   MapComponent;

async ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.userInfo   =   await Promise.resolve(this.storage.get('user')) || {};      
    this.firebaseCtrl.subscribeToRef(infoVoucher.data().currentRoute).subscribe(data =>{

        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

        console.log(this.mapComponent) // inside the subscribe it works, return the instance of my component

        this.getInstanceMyComponent()   // do exact the same thing (console.log), inside the method and it returns undefined        
    });


}
```

The fact is that I can just access to my `ViewChild` inside the subscribe, and not in a method that is called inside the subscribe. Actually the method is the `ionViewDidEnter` but I've tried all of them, `AfterViewInit` too. What could it be the reason?

Comment: What is the mapcomponent

Comment: It is a component, viewChild